# How to deserialize to property by attribute name and inner xml

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I have an xml like this:

```
<employees>
  <employee id="11629">
   <field id="displayName">First Last</field>
   <field id="email">test@test.com</field>
  </employee>
</employees>
```

and I created a class:

```
public class Employee
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

For Id everything works perfectly, but I can't figure out how but attribute we can set value to DisplayName property.

Please help.

Comment: Is it required that the XML remains the same or could it be changed slightly?

Comment: No, xml comes from another (not my) application. I know the structure of xml not very good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:

```
public class Employee
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("field")]
    public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return Fields.Where(i => i.Id == "displayName").FirstOrDefault().Value;
        } 
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get
        {
            return Fields.Where(i => i.Id == "email").FirstOrDefault().Value;
        }
    }
}

public class Field
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that I can have more than 1 "field" tags. I've updated the question.

Comment: Yeah... I think it is only one proper way. I did it also before looks like impossible to do what I want.