# Deserializing complex XML

Tags: c#, xml

I receive the following XML from an app called Ctera:

```
<obj class="TeamPortal">
    <att id="activationStatus">
        <val>Enabled</val>
    </att>
    <att id="name">
        <val>dana</val>
    </att>
    <att id="createDate">
        <val>2015-06-04T10:01:13</val>
    </att>
    <att id="alerts">
    </att>
    <att id="autoAssignmentRules">
        <list></list>
    </att>
    <att id="totalStorage">
        <obj class="TotalStorage">
            <att id="totalAvailable">
                <val>0</val>
            </att>
            <att id="totalInUse">
                <val>0</val>
            </att>
        </obj>
    </att>
</obj>
```

I want to deserialize it to an object like the following:

```
public class TeamPortal
{
    public string activationStatus { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public string createDate { get; set; }

    public string alerts { get; set; }

    public List<string> autoAssignmentRules { get; set; }

    public TotalStorage totalStorage { get; set; }
}

public class TotalStorage
{
    public int totalAvailable { get; set; }

    public int totalInUse { get; set; }
}
```

I try to avoid parsing it to a key-value list.
I don't have any control on the XML I receive.

Comment: It's definetaly a Key-Value based structure. Most of C# serialization based on Node-s.

Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279665/how-to-deserialize-to-property-by-attribute-name-and-inner-xml

Comment: This is simply a badly designed schema.You can't deserialize an XML file to an object structure that's completely different. You need to either transform the XML file using XSLT before deserialization or map the key/value pairs to the desired structure *after* deserialization. A possible workaround would be to create two classes derived from DynamicObject that resolve property access calls to key/value pair lookups

Comment: Add following before your List<> object : [XmlElement("autoAssignmentRules")].  The XmlElement eliminates an unnecessary tag from the XML output.

Comment: What does the XML look like when the `autoAssignmentRules` list is populated?